# How do I add custom field in to model that extends AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, django-users

I'm trying to create my own User class called Customer which extends the AbstractUser model and has an additional field called address. When I register, I see the user has been created in Django admin and all the fields (username, first name, last name and email) are seen in the django admin screen but I see no value in the "address" field. How do I know if the address is being saved and how can I display it in the admin site?

Below is my code for the models.py

```
class Customer(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    deladdress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def signupPage(request):
    signForm = CreateCustomer()
    if request.method=='POST':
        signForm = CreateCustomer(request.POST)
        if signForm.is_valid():
            signForm.save()

    return render(request, 'trial_app/signup.html', {'signForm':signForm})
```

forms.py

```
class CreateCustomer(UserCreationForm):
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','address','password1','password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CreateCustomer, self).save(commit=False)
        user.address = self.cleaned_data["address"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Here are some pictures that are the input to my html form and the value in the admin site
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when you save a form in its `save` method you use
`user.address = self.cleaned_data["address"]`, however, `Customer` model does not have `address` field, it has `deladdress`, so try to rename a field, or use `user.deladdress` in your `save` method of `CreateCustomer` form.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! It's weird because firstly I had "address" as the field name but it didn't work when I had user.address.